Category has wrong URL
We just upgraded to 2.4.6 and we have found tons of products and categories with wrong URLs.
Categories and products that work have this URL :catalog/category/view/s/produkter/id/622/
Categories and products that do not work have this URL: /produkter.html/brannvern.html
Does anyone know how to fix this? we have found 169k products and categories that have the wrong URL. So hopefully the fix is not a manual job.

That sounds like an issue with your URL rewrites. If you go to Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites are you seeing any there for the categories in question? If not you will need to create them. I've used this module in the past in order to regenerate the URLs https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

If you do see URL rewrites, ensure they match what you would expect, the example you gave has the html extension multiple times, which seems non standard for magento. You may need to tweak the settings which control whether .html is appended to the paths.

I tried this, and still not working. I ran one for Products and then 1 for the categories. But products are not showing still. And we have an issue with Catalog search index

You can try the following steps.

Take the backup of current Database.
Empty the url_rewrite table from the database.
Now open the CLI.
Run the following command.


php bin/magento indexer:reindex


Hi, I tried to truncate the table but got this error: ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (xxxxxx_xxxxxxx.catalog_url_rewrite_product_category, CONSTRAINT FK_BB79E64705D7F17FE181F23144528FC8 FOREIGN KEY (url_rewrite_id) REFERENCES ab140e0b_19423437.url_rewrite (`url_r)

You need to empty the table data only.
